# Angular - Parsing multiple files is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, ngfor

I am trying to upload multiple files coming from an *ngFor block. I am not able to parse through the contents properly

I am using an array to store the filenames, and if I try to select a file again, I am not able to get the new filename

this is my html code

```
  <div *ngFor="let data of fileList, let i = index">

    <label class="adpLabel">{{data.fileDesc}}</label>   
    <input readonly  type="text" value={{filename[i]}}>
    <input type="file" id="{{data.fileName}}" name="{{data.lastUpdateTsFile}}"
    #selectFiles hidden accept=".xls,.xlsx" (change)="getFileInfo($event, i)">
    <button mat-button (click)="selectFiles.click()" class="browseBtn">Browse</button>    
 </div>
```

this is my component.ts file

```
export class appComponent implements OnInit {


 fileType : any = [];
 filename : any = [];
 file : any = [] ;


 getFileInfo(event, i) {

this.file.push(event.target.files);
this.fileType.push(event.target.id);
this.fileUploadDate.push(event.target.name);

for (let i = 0; i < this.file.length; i++) {
  let fileName = this.file[i][0].name; 
  let id = this.fileType[i];
  let fileDate = this.fileUploadDate[i];
  let extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase();

  if ( extension==".xls" || extension==".xlsx" ) {

    this.filename[i] = fileName; 
    this.fileType[i] = id;

    }

  }
}
  }
```

I expect to browse for the file multiple times which I am not able to do now.

Comment: Can you please update your code in stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbm5vd @Anusha_Mamidala

Comment: should you maintain multiple browse buttons or can you maintain single browse buttons and then able to choose multiple files

Comment: As per the requirements, we should have multiple browse buttons

Comment: I have answered the question try it out and let me know if you have any problem

Comment: data.fileName is wrong, filename does not come from that data

Comment: the functionality is working fine, but the j value is not updating, it is showing as Zero for every iteration @Anusha_Mamidala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your ts file into

```
getFileInfo(event, i) {
   if(this.file[i]){
      this.file.splice(i,1,event.target.files);
      this.fileType.splice(i,1,event.target.id);
   }
   else{
      this.file[i]=event.target.files;
      this.fileType[i]=event.target.id;
      //this.file.push(event.target.files);
      //this.fileType.push(event.target.id);
   }
   for (let j = 0; j < this.file.length; j++) {
      let fileName:string='';
      let extension:string;
      if(event.target.files[j]){
       fileName=event.target.files[j].name;
       extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")).toLowerCase();
      } 
      let id:any; 
      if(this.fileType[j]){
        id=this.fileType[j];
      }
      if ( extension==".xls" || extension==".xlsx" ) {
        this.filename[i] = fileName; 
        this.fileType[i] = id;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you specify the issue

Comment: Can you please explain your question clearly.... in which array what you want to store and to what purpose you want to use it.... and why do you need to maintain 4 different arrays... for  name,type and all.... !!

Comment: I got it. I have made the following change
from this

 let fileName = event.target.files[i].name; 

to this: 

  let fileName = this.file[i][0].name;

Comment: now it is working. but I have another issue. Let's suppose I have 3 browse buttons, and if I select the 3rd browse button first, the name is displayed in the 1st textbox and not in the 3rd textbox linked to that button

Comment: you can refer to the stackblitz I shared

Comment: Yeah sure ill do and share the changes

Comment: made changes you are good to go now..let me know if you have any issues